# How to append one column from table1 to table2 in HIve?

Tags: sql, hiveql

How to append one column from table1 to table2 in HIve?

[image]

```
Table1       Table2
******       ******
x   y        a    b
1   3        3   10
2   4        5    4
3   5        8    1
```

Output

```
******

a    b   x
3   10   1
5    4   2
8    1   3
```

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63829028/concatinate-a-column-to-a-table-in-hive)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming column x & column a values will always increase & those corresponding records needs to be brought side by side - you can use the logic below. But the question is still not fully clear (since ideally you would need an ordering column or an ID column to bring them together. Those columns might be x & a in your case but it is not clear from the question). However, the below query should work for your example.

```
Select Tb1.a, Tb1.b, Tb2.x
from
 (Select a,b, row_number() over(order by a) as rn1 from Table2) Tb1
 join (Select x, row_number() over(order by x) as rn2 from Table1) Tb2
 on Tb1.rn1 = Tb2.rn2 ;
```